# python: How to read occurrences of character in file

Tags: python, count

I want to display how many occurrences there are of each letter in a text-file.

```
f=file.read()

for i in f:
if str(i) == '\n':
    pass
else:
    print("There are ",f.count(i),str(i),"'s in the text.")
```

This is not really good as I get n duplicates of that text for n occurrences of the symbol. What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: all you need is `c = Counter(file.read())`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked well for the task I had:

```
x=0
while x<10000:  ## or some sufficiently high number
    if chr(x) == "\n":
        x+=1
    elif chr(x) in someFile:
        print("There are ", f.count(chr(x)), chr(x),"'s in the text.")
        x+=1
    else:
        x+=1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a `Counter`. But you can initialize a dictionary of letters with zero, and count the frequency. Let's consider a quick example to illustrate the idea.

```
import string
letterCounter= dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase,[0]*26))
data = '''\
I am trying to count words
file is compsed by lines 
lines by words 
words are composed by letters
'''

for line in data.splitlines():
    for word in line.split():
        for letter in list(word.lower()):
            letterCounter[letter]+=1
print letterCounter
```

Output:

```
{'a': 2, 'c': 3, 'b': 3, 'e': 8, 'd': 5, 'g': 1, 'f': 1, 'i': 6, 'h': 0, 'k': 0, 'j': 0, 'm': 3, 'l': 4, 'o': 8, 'n': 4, 'q': 0, 'p': 2, 's': 9, 'r': 6, 'u': 1, 't': 5, 'w': 3, 'v': 0, 'y': 4, 'x': 0, 'z': 0}
```

To use the same code on a text file, you need to read the file by using `Open(..)`

```
with open('filename.txt') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        for word in line.split():
            for letter in list(word):
                letterCounter[letter]+=1
print letterCounter
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. Although I just did "for letter in f: letter counter[letter]+=1". i.e. didn't go line>word>letter.

Comment: this is not how to use counter nor how to open a file