# Python count occurences

Tags: python

Problem: I have a long-ish txt file where I need to count occurences for each character/letter. Numbers, commas, punctuation marks etc are not to be counted. After counting, I need to convert to relative frequency and print a list in order high-to-low relative frequency. Please help anybody.

With great failure I have tried this:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    input_string = norec_corpus.txt
print("The input string is:", input_string)
mySet = set(input_string)
for element in mySet:
    countofChar = 0
    for character in input_string:
        if character == element:
            countofChar +=1
    print("Count of character '{}' is '{}'".format(element, countofChar))
```

Comment: just use `collections.Counter` and then filter out keys that are not alphabetic letters.

Comment: The same question is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148903/letter-frequency-in-python/5148987#5148987

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Letter frequency in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148903/letter-frequency-in-python)

Comment: Not really. 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: `raw_input()` in python2 is like `input()` in python3.

Comment: How about this? Doesn't this answer your question? [python: How to read occurrences of character in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791697/python-how-to-read-occurrences-of-character-in-file)